# .load() little part without toggle

Tags: php, jquery, html, load, toggle

I have a conversations flow who is refresh with .load() of jQuery every 3 seconds.

This system work, but in each conversation I have an answer button who slide a form (textarea and submit button) with .toggle().

To display the flow, I use a while with PHP.

My issue is, when the  is loading by .load(), and answer button is clicked, the form hide again and text contain too.

```
<div id="the_river_loading">
<?php
$sql_the_river = 'SELECT u.nickname, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.main_photo, u.locality,
             id_conversation, id_messages, owner, participants, text, date
          FROM users AS u
          INNER JOIN the_river
          ON u.nickname = owner
          WHERE answer = 0
          ORDER BY date DESC';
$result_the_river = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_the_river);

$count = 0;
while ($data_the_river = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_the_river))
{
   $count++;
   echo '<div class="message_container_news">'; // Start block conversation

   echo '<a href="/profile/' . $nickname . '" class="name_links" style="vertical-align: top; font-size: 16px;">
   <img src="' . $main_photo . '"  title="' . $name . '" class="members_actu_photo" />' . $name . '</a>
   <span style="vertical-align: top">, ' . $locality . '</span><span style="float: right; font-size: 12px;">Posté le Octobre 25, 2012</span>
   <p style="margin-top: 5px;">' . $data_the_river['text'] . '</p>
   <div class="btnAnswer_nb">' . $count_answer . '</div> Answers
   <a href="/news/' . $data_the_river['id_conversation'] . '" style="margin-left: 100px; display: inline;" class="global_links">See conversation</a>

   <div class="btnAnswer_news" id="btnAnswer_news_id_' . $count . '">Reply</div>
   <form method="post" id="display_form_id_' . $count . '" action="" style="display: none;">
      <br />
      <textarea name="answer_text"></textarea><br />
      <input type="submit" name="answer_valid_id_' . $count . '" value="Post" />
   </form>
   </div>'; // End block conversation
}
?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">     
$(".btnAnswer_news").live("click", function(){
   var num_show = this.id.replace(/\D/g, "");
   $("#display_form_id_" + num_show).toggle("fast");
});

var auto_refresh = setInterval(
   function() {
      $("#the_river_loading").load("/home" + " .message_container_news");
   }, 3000
);
</script>
```

In pleasure of read you.

Answer (score 0):

This is because if you load the content again into the container, the styles applied per js will get removed (because they were applied through style="" and this gets refreshed). You should move the Form and the Button to another Div, wich is not in the loading Div.

Comment: Thanks for you answer,

Yes, but how do that ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly (you've not be very descriptive), you just want to not hide the form when clicking again, for that use `show()` instead of `toggle()` , so replace your following line:

```
$("#display_form_id_" + num_show).toggle("fast");
```

for this one:

```
$("#display_form_id_" + num_show).show("fast");
```

If you want to keep the text of the textarea, you can like so:

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
   function() {
      tx = $("#the_river_loading textarea[name='answer_text']").val();
      $("#the_river_loading").load("/home" + " .message_container_news", function(){
          $("#the_river_loading textarea[name='answer_text']").val(tx);
      });
   }, 3000
);
```

Comment: Even if textarea still "open", the contained text delete after reload. Does not work.

Do you understand ?

Comment: Thank you. 
But the text is print in all textarea and even with .show(), the textarea is hidden after 3 seconds because the global div is refresh.